# Syntax error using expression object.property as directive attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I can't use an expression with form object.property in certain situations:

```
<raty score="{{obj.rating}}"></raty>
```

Or:

```
<div ng-init="myvar=obj.rating" />
<raty score="{{myvar}}"></raty>
```

In both cases JS complains: "Error: Syntax Error: Token 'obj.rating' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{obj.rating}}] starting at [obj.rating}}].
" or "Error: Syntax Error: Token 'myvar' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{myvar}}] starting at [myvar}}].".

The background story (for what I need this) is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210159/jquery-raty-and-angularjs).

I have already tried many things, read a few threads like: 
[Optional expression attribute in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226531/angularjs-directives-evaluating-expression-optional-attribute)
or [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/angularjs-how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

But it doesn't seem to address this specific problem of calling object.property. I need it this way because I'm iterating through a JSON document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just `<div ng-init="myvar = obj.rating" />`?

Comment: Sorry this was not expressed correctly, edited now the post.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I did the plunker and there it works. I guess I have to review my code...

Comment: Plunker helped me accidentally finding the reason/solution - they provide the most recent (not stable) version of Angular and there it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in AngularJS (not stable) version 1.1.5. I was working with the currently stable version 1.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation doesn't work in the attributes in the tags like `<raty score="{{obj.rating}}"></raty>`. One possible way to do it is creating a template in the directive and then apply the directive to the HTML control.

**Updated:**

With 1.1.5 it works.

Comment: Not true - I just could do it with Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kgsKs6Boe7rcOLCp0abH?p=preview

Comment: It seems they changed this. You are probably right concerning the current stable version. With 1.1.5 it works.

Comment: @lxx Thanks. I am not quite following the unstable version, but it is good to know.