# Conditional focus

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myAppName');

    app.directive('smFocus', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',            
            link: function (scope, element) {

                scope.$on('sm:focus', function () {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element[0].focus();
                    }, 10);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

I also have these two controls:

```
<input type="text"
                               name="nickname"
                               id="nickname"
                               ng-model="currentDynamicRule.nickname"
                               class="form-control"
                               ng-disabled="!isNew"
                               placeholder="Nickname"
                               required
                               ng-maxlength="10"
                               sm-focus />
```

and another one

```
 <input type="text" name="descrip" id="descrip" ng-model="currentDynamicRule.descrip" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Description" required ng-maxlength="30"
                           sm-focus />
```

So, two controls where the first one is only enabled when it's a new row (disabled in Edit mode). I want to have the first control focused when it's a new record and the second control focused when it's in edit mode.

I am using ASP.NET MVC. Right now in both edit and new modes I have the second control focused. I am not sure how to make this focus conditional.

Comment: how is `edit mode` and `new row` triggered? is it by clicking a button?

Comment: We start from a grid view and by double clicking on a row in a grid we open form in edit mode (or by clicking edit button). For the new row it is a new button click. The isNew variable tells if it's a new row or existing row. In the ng-disabled directive we use "!isNew" (so in edit mode it's disabled)

Answer (score 1):

hmm I had written a directive before wherein it accepts an event and an element id to focus when that event has been triggered.

It's something like this(**[Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/goI4tchrL9oWd5GhrDIG?p=preview)**):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .directive('eventFocus', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.on(attr.eventFocus, function() {
        // timeout makes sure that is invoked after any other event has been triggered.
        // e.g. click events that need to run before the focus or
        // inputs elements that are in a disabled state but are enabled when those events
        // are triggered.
        $timeout(function() {
          var element = document.getElementById(attr.eventFocusId);
          if(element)
            element.focus();
        });
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        element.off(attr.eventFocus);
      });
    };
  })
```

**HTML** (Possible implementation)

```
<input type="text" id="pet-desc" ng-model="pet.desc">
<button type="button" event-focus="click" event-focus-id="pet-desc">Edit</button
```

When Edit Button is clicked, input with id="pet-desc" is focused.

**UPDATE:**
To identify between which `sm-focus` element is the target for the `sm:focus` event, you can add an argument(the id of the element to focus to) within your `$rootScope.$broadcast()`. **[See this PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRqYbT4E8o0OP4dKboZU?p=preview)**.

e.g.

**Controller**

```
$rotoScope.$broadcast('sm:focus', 'pet-id');
```

**Directive**

```
  directive('smFocus', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$on('sm:focus', function(event, id) {
        $timeout(function() {
          if(attr.id == id)
            elem[0].focus();
        });
      });
    };
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of a slightly different approach. I was thinking is it possible to add an optional parameter to our current directive to turn it off? In this case we would be able to still use sm-focus as I have it currently, but have no-focus property? Do you think it's possible to have such extra optional parameter in the directive? Can you help me with the implementation this way? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks. I think your solution is still not what I am after. This directive is used in our application in many forms. I want my change to be as small as possible. Here is my not working attempt so far:              link: function (scope, element) {
                var noFocus = angular.isDefined(element[0].noFocus) ? element[0].noFocus : false;
                console.log('noFocus=' + noFocus)
                if (!noFocus) {
                    scope.$on('sm:focus', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element[0].focus

Comment: However, I see false in the console window, so it's not working. I want my changes to be as unobtrusive as possible. I am using this code in the form  <input type="text" name="descrip" id="descrip" ng-model="currentDynamicRule.descrip" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Description" required ng-maxlength="30"
                           sm-focus  no-focus="isNew" />  Do you know how to make my idea to work?

Comment: I think I got it! Using idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226531/angularjs-directives-evaluating-expression-optional-attribute

Comment: by your statement "I want my changes to be as unobtrusive as possbile" what I did was simply that?, adding a `no-focus` attribute is already obtrusive in nature. Additionally, how will you determine which `sm-focus` element is the target to focus to, when you don't have any indicators?

Comment: Please see my current implementation. Do you think it's bad? I am testing other forms in the meantime.

Comment: I checked a few more forms, they seem to work Ok. So, my particular form works the way I want and all other forms work normal.

Comment: In your sample, how can I make the attribute to be optional if I want to re-use the existing sm-focus directive?

Comment: You don't have to? in your controller you can decide which input element you want to focus via `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Comment: the first argument is the event name `sm:focus` the second argument is the id of the input element you want to focus

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current implementation that seems to be working! Need to test more:

```
app.directive('smFocus', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                noFocus: "=?"
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var noFocus = angular.isDefined(scope.noFocus) ? scope.noFocus : false;
               // console.log('noFocus=' + noFocus)
                if (!noFocus) {
                    scope.$on('sm:focus', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element[0].focus();
                        }, 10);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

And my form controls are:

```
 <input type="text"
                           name="nickname"
                           id="nickname"
                           ng-model="currentDynamicRule.nickname"
                           class="form-control"
                           ng-disabled="!isNew"
                           placeholder="Nickname"
                           required
                           ng-maxlength="10"
                           no-focus="!isNew"
                           sm-focus />
```

And similar for description:

```
 <input type="text" name="descrip" id="descrip" ng-model="currentDynamicRule.descrip" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Description" required ng-maxlength="30"
                           no-focus="isNew"
                           sm-focus />
```

The form works as I want it. I am going to test few more forms to make sure this change didn't break anything.

Comment: have you tried to add an element, edit afterwards and then add another one? see if it works?

Comment: Agree. In that form 2 elements currently have sm-focus. In other forms only one input element has that attribute. I think I am Ok with that implementation as the directive works with or without that optional attribute. BTW, not sure I understand your comment?